# Find the first 300 members of the server

Tags: discord.js

I want to create a bot that can tell me the list of the first 300 members of my server. Is this possible with Discord.js? Any help would be appreciated. I just don't know where to start

Comment: first 300 members you can fetch or first 300 to join?

Comment: First 300 members to join the server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get the first 300 members that joined the guild, you can use the [`GuildMember.joinedAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedAt) property. You would go through these steps:

- Fetch all the members in the guild: you can use [`Guild.members.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) for that
- Sort them by the date you get from the [`joinedAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedAt) property
- Get the first 300

Here's how I would do it:

```js
guild.members.fetch() // Fectch all the members in the guild
  .then(members => {
    let first300 = members
      .sort((a, b) => a.joinedAt - b.joinedAt) // Order them by they date the joined the guild
      .first(300) // Take the first 300
  })
```

Comment: You can also not convert it into an array and just use `first(300)`

Comment: Yeah, I guess so

Answer (score 0):

Like syntle asked it depends which kinda but, here's the first 300 to fetch:
Might not work since there might be an already set limit of members you can fetch

```js
const members = await <Guild>.members.fetch({ limit: 300 });
//or if you are fine with cached
const members = <Guild>.members.cache.array();
members.length = 300;
```

Comment: Why would it only get the 300th member? Setting an array's (or string's) length is a quick way to limit the length, it will not only only return the 300th member as far as I am aware. But I saw the other comment of using `.first(300)` which is better I guess

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I was testing it and did a mistake, that's why I thought it wouldn't work.